# confusion on .module in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

http://jsbin.com/vurayayeqa/edit?html,js,output

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function() {
  this.name = 'World';
});
```

I'm seen in most of the tutorial they do angular.module('app',[]), what does app mean? is it just the name of the module? I've seen in few large project where the name of the module never change, it's always `app`. I'm confused what is the .module method for.

Second question is why the above example doesn't work with this keyword? it worked if I do

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

Comment: It's the name you chose to name the module.

Comment: @Erevald what is it for? I want to know how to use the module in angularjs. The purpose is it to create multiple modules? can modules talk to each other?

Comment: `this.` vs `$scope` is already explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14168699/1373110)

Comment: @NatelyJamerson you can define this ``var myApp = angular.module('myApp ', []);``

Comment: then ``myApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});``

Comment: @DonaldWu I know and I've use angular for quite some time but why? What's the point of having multiple modules?

Comment: @NatelyJamerson no idea, but u can see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512434/multiple-module-in-angularjs